# git status On branch master Initial commit shows Untracked files:

Tags: git

On branch `master`, I see:

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
.CFUserTextEncoding
.Trash/
.adobe/
.bash_history
.bash_sessions/
.config/
.cups/
.dvdcss/
.gitconfig
.ssh/
.tblive-4/
.viminfo
Applications/
Desktop/
Documents/
Downloads/
Library/
Movies/
Music/
Pictures/
Public/
```

Nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "`git add`" to track)

Is this normal? Should I see that amount of untracked files?

Comment: you are just seeing a list of all the files and folders in you home directory... which is completely normal if you did `git init` in your home folder

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have initialized your git repo in your `%USERPROFILE%` path, which would include not only your project but *all* other files/folders of your user account.

You need to do a [`git init`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) only within the root folder of your project.